# I was told I'd be getting an offer letter by early this month, but its 10th already. Should I ask my hiring manager again?

Tags: job-offer

I was contacted by a manager, whom I'd worked with earlier, that he had a position for me. After a week of silence, I called him to ask him if there was a timeline to the offer letter. I was told I'd be getting the offer letter early this month and its 10th already. Should I call him again? Is there a chance things have changed with the position and I have not been informed? What could be taking so long?

Comment: You didn't say how long it's been since the most recent call. If it's been another full week or more, I think it's worth asking whether something got lost in the mail or, if not, roughly when you should expect to see it. Eagerness is a positive, after all, as long as it doesn't cross over into pestering.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I call him again?

That depends on when you called him last.

If you called more than 2 weeks ago, then call him again. Otherwise wait until at least 2 weeks have gone by.

> Is there a chance things have changed with the position and I have not
>   been informed?

Certainly there's a chance. That's probably unlikely, but there is always a chance.

> What could be taking so long?

Lots of things can cause a delay

- Perhaps the hiring manager is on vacation or otherwise busy
- Often, offer letters have to be written by HR. Perhaps the HR person is on vacation or otherwise busy
- Perhaps funding for the position is not yet complete
- Perhaps there are still other candidates to get through

Try to be patient, and not be so worried. It will most likely become clear what is going on very soon.

Answer (score 1):

You are speculating way too much, and that's not a real substitute for getting things  done.

Giving someone five business days is courteous but beyond that, you don't want to create a perception that you are being dilatory.

Follow up with him immediately, say that it's been ten days and that you are following up on his expectation that you will be getting an offer letter early in the month.

There are several possible reasons why you are not getting that letter including wrong address, wrong name, etc. none of which have anything to do with them changing their minds about giving you the offer.

If the fact, they changed their minds, you have the right to know that they changed their minds.